# Jupyter dashboard server - part of the stack or traffic not working

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I'm having trouble understanding which part of the jupyter dashboard server doesn't work.
It seems like the dashboard server is working, the kernel gateway is working and the kernel gets started up, but for some reason after the startup the websocket traffic to kernel gets 404 as a response.

I've tried to do a curl request on the kernel gateway, but curl doesn't support the 'ws' protocol.

How can I debug this further? All the details below.

I have a VM (debian jessie) with this Apache configuration:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
```

I have the dashboard server, which is responding:

```
GET /dashboards/Environment_variables 200 39.408 ms - 2400
GET /css/style.css 200 1.688 ms - 186626
GET /components/require.js 200 3.943 ms - 86262
GET /components/dashboard.js 200 1.351 ms - 788654
GET /components/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3 304 0.689 ms - -
GET /components/dashboard.js.map 304 0.621 ms - -
POST /api/kernels?1475506860562 201 923.933 ms - 62
GET /api/kernels/d7681c2f-b8f9-4b19-9893-6bd6022d0e77/channels?session_id=ad17021f13dd752eb2e687b4a78fee64 404 2.936 ms - 1021
GET /api/kernels/d7681c2f-b8f9-4b19-9893-6bd6022d0e77/channels?session_id=ad17021f13dd752eb2e687b4a78fee64 404 3.703 ms - 1021
```

Albeit with the 404 in the end.

Then I have the kernel gateway running:

```
[KernelGatewayApp] The Jupyter Kernel Gateway is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888
[KernelGatewayApp] Native kernel (python3) available from /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
[KernelGatewayApp] Starting kernel: ['/opt/anaconda3/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel', '-f', '/home/sandman/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-d7681c2f-b8f9-4b19-9893-6bd6022d0e77.json']
[KernelGatewayApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52565
[KernelGatewayApp] Kernel started: d7681c2f-b8f9-4b19-9893-6bd6022d0e77
[KernelGatewayApp] Kernel args: {'kernel_name': 'python3'}
[I 161003 16:01:01 web:1971] 201 POST /api/kernels (127.0.0.1) 917.05ms
```

Which sees the request for a kernel and as far as I understand, starts it up.

But the browser doesn't see it:

```
Environment_variables   200 document    Other   1.2 KB  365 ms  
style.css   200 stylesheet  Environment_variables:7 29.2 KB 259 ms  
require.js  200 script  Environment_variables:64    21.0 KB 325 ms  
dashboard.js    200 script  Environment_variables:65    214 KB  989 ms  
fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3   304 font    Environment_variables:64    216 B   82 ms   
kernels?1475506860562   201 xhr index.js:178    395 B   1.01 s  
cursor.png  200 png middlemouse.js:53   (from cache)    2 ms    
channels?session_id=ad17021f13dd752eb2e687b4a78fee64    404 websocket   Other   0 B 82 ms   
channels?session_id=ad17021f13dd752eb2e687b4a78fee64    404 websocket   Other   0 B 82 ms
```

[image]

I also tried starting up the kernel gateway in http mode, but that just gave me an error:

```
$ jupyter kernelgateway --KernelGatewayApp.api=kernel_gateway.notebook_http --debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-kernelgateway", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(launch_instance())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 652, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kernel_gateway/gatewayapp.py", line 298, in initialize
    self.init_configurables()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kernel_gateway/gatewayapp.py", line 352, in init_configurables
    self.personality = func(parent=self, log=self.log)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kernel_gateway/notebook_http/__init__.py", line 144, in create_personality
    return NotebookHTTPPersonality(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kernel_gateway/notebook_http/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.api_parser = func(parent=self, log=self.log, kernelspec=self.parent.kernel_manager.seed_kernelspec, notebook_cells=self.parent.seed_notebook.cells)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cells'
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    ProxyPassMatch "/api/kernels/(.*)/channels" "ws://127.0.0.1:3000/api/kernels/$1/channels"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api/kernels" "ws://127.0.0.1:3000/api/kernels"

    ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
```

The point was that I was translating websocket traffic into http traffic with the last two lines. So of course it didn't work.

The added middle lines patternmatch the websocket requests and pass those to ws: protocol.

Also, the order of the lines is important, because ProxyPass "/" matches everything and Apache goes through the list until it finds something that matches. So the "match everything" line has to be last.